# SQL table accepting same names again and again database name checking

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert

I am trying to insert the guestpass type name in table `guestpasstypes` and at a time it will check the database whether the database has already that name or not by using this statement:

```
@"INSERT INTO guestpasstypes(guestPasstype_Name)values('" + tbPassType.Text + "') where not exists (select 'guestPasstype_Name' from guestpasstypes where guestPasstype_Name = '" + tbPassType.Text + "')"
```

but it accepts the duplicate name too, and it does not work. Would anyone please help on this?

Comment: Make a UNIQUE KEY on `guestpasstypes.guestPasstype_Name`

Comment: And then just use: `"INSERT INTO guestpasstypes(guestPasstype_Name)values('" + tbPassType.Text + "')"` Don't do work that the db should be doing.

Comment: Are you having the same problem in sql server and mysql? Otherwise, correct your tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to throw an error you can either :

- Put a unique index on the column (the easiest and preferred way)

or

- Write a stored procedure which returns an error flag. Within the procedure, you first check for a matching value and if one is found, set the error flag and return. Otherwise do the insert as normal.

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server it would look like this.

```
insert into guestpasstypes (guestPasstype_Name)
select 'name1'
where not exists (select *
                  from guestpasstypes
                  where guestPasstype_Name = 'name1')
```

I think it should work for MySQL as well.

If you are on SQL Server 2008 you can use [MERGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx).

```
merge guestpasstypes as G
using (select 'name2') as S(Name)
on G.guestPasstype_Name = S.Name
when not matched then
  insert (guestPasstype_Name) values (Name);
```

---

**UPDATE**

I think the first option could be applied to your problem like this:

```
@"INSERT INTO guestpasstypes(guestPasstype_Name) select '" + tbPassType.Text
  + "' where not exists (select * from guestpasstypes where guestPasstype_Name = '"
  + tbPassType.Text + "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try either INSERT IGNORE or INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `guestpasstypes`(`guestPasstype_Name`) values('" + tbPassType.Text + "');
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO `guestpasstypes`(`guestPasstype_Name`)values('" + tbPassType.Text + "') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `guestPasstype_Name` = `guestPasstype_Name`;
```

Comment: but in both ways its not working. I have already guestpasstype name is "notcompleted" in my database when i am trying to insert again the name  "notcompleted" it will taking that name again rather not showing the error    pls help me guys... many thanks

Comment: Are you saying that you want it to throw an error? Thats not in your original question. Are you sure that the duplicate row is actually being inserted?

Comment: ya rather than accepting name again it has to throw an error I am sure the duplicate row has inserted