# problem entering the same name into database

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, insert-update

Hi I am trying to insert the guestpass type name   in table guestpasstypes and at a time it will check the database whether the database has already that name or not  by using this statement

```
@"INSERT INTO guestpasstypes(guestPasstype_Name)values('" + tbPassType.Text + "') where not exists (select 'guestPasstype_Name' from guestpasstypes where guestPasstype_Name = '" + tbPassType.Text + "')"
```

but it accepts the duplicate name also.. and it does not work

I have tried all techniques like WHERE NOT EXSIST types 
pls help

Comment: Have you tried "INSERT INTO guestpasstypes(guestPasstype_Name) values('" + tbPassType.Text + "') where guestPasstype_Name != '" + your string name + "'"

Comment: do you have a unique constraint on the field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [sql table accepting same names again and again database name checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383618/sql-table-accepting-same-names-again-and-again-database-name-checking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a unique constraint. Check out this previous question:
[How do I specify unique constraint for multiple columns in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635937/how-do-i-specify-unique-constraint-for-multiple-columns-in-mysql)